# Jquery bootstrap multiselect optgroup selection

Tags: jquery, optgroup

I am using Jquery bootstrap multiselect plugin which seems pretty good and fulfill most of the requirements which i needed.

The only additional functionality i want is to add checkbox to OptGroup so if user wants to select complete group they can select all by clicking it.

any help appreciated.

http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#examples

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('.multiselect-group').before('<input type="checkbox" />');
$(document).on('click', '.multiselect-group', function(event) {
    var checkAll = true;
    var $opts = $(this).parent().nextUntil(':has(.multiselect-group)'); 
    var $inactive = $opts.filter(':not(.active)'); 
    var $toggleMe = $inactive;
    if ($inactive.length == 0) { 
        $toggleMe = $opts;
        checkAll = false;
    }
    $toggleMe.find('input').click();
    $(this).parent().find('input').attr('checked', checkAll);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: It works well only i can tweak the UI to look adjust checkbox alignment. the only problem is if you select optgroup checkbox drop down automatically gets close. any work around ?

Comment: I believe that is from the click event handler on the list parent. Use event.preventDefault(). I'll update the answer to show this.

Comment: any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you click on opt group label it does check all childs but still hiding drop down.

Answer (score 6):

No need to do any code to achieve your requirement.

There is an option called `enableClickableOptGroups` in this plugin to select all options of `optgroup`

http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-enableClickableOptGroups

Answer (score 4):

You can use `event.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 1):

After I checked an option group and then unchecked it, if I wanted to check it again, it would check all options from the group, but the group remained unchecked.

In order for the option group to be properly displayed as checked/unchecked after several retries, replace:

```
$(this).parent().find('input').**attr**('checked', checkAll);
```

with

```
$(this).parent().find('input').**prop**('checked', checkAll);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code put this line of code only

enableClickableOptGroups: true

this will enable the option to select group

http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started